# sql log shipping

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

Our log shipping routine failed and was 3 days out of date, so I manually restored the transaction log from the primary database into the secondary database.

The database seemed to restore all ok but now the secondary database is not showing as "StandBy Read-Only", so i am worried that i have done something wrong!

Can i just set the database to be "StandBy Read-Only", how would i do that?

Or have i caused further issues?

This is on a MS SQL 2008R2 setup.

Answer (score 0):

**Run the below command to change this configuration setting using T-SQL:
This command will set the secondary database in a STANDBY MODE.**

```
EXEC sp_change_log_shipping_secondary_database

@secondary_database = 'Collection',
@restore_mode = 1,
@disconnect_users =1
```

For more information you can refer to the following link:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3574/change-sql-server-log-shipped-database-from-restoring-to-standby-readonly/